# Create an Android ImageButton with a Shape

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageButton and want to scale the button in different sizes which means an image is not the right choice. So I was thinking of an ImageButton with a custom Shape as source.

I want the button to look like this:

[image]

I started with this, but got stuck with the rotate stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="135" >
        <shape android:shape="line" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/red" >
            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </rotate>

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

</shape>
```

This however does not rotate as I expect it to. Maybe I am completely wrong and need a push in the right direction. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around that problem with a custom `Button` implementation and overwrite the `onDraw()` method which looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    width = getMeasuredWidth();
    height = getMeasuredHeight();

    // diagonal top left | bottom right
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, width, height, mPaint);

    // diagonal top right | bottom left
    canvas.drawLine(width, 0, 0, height, mPaint);

    // horizontal top
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0, mPaint);

    // horizontal bottom
    canvas.drawLine(0, height, width, height, mPaint);

    // vertical left
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, height, mPaint);

    //vertical right
    canvas.drawLine(width, 0, width, height, mPaint);
}
```

You have to set `mPaint` yourself according to the color and size etc. you want your stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a Bitmap and scaling it depending on your needs using Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...) method. Then you can easily convert it to a BitmapDrawable and then assign this BitmapDrawable as the background of the button using  (name-of-your-button).setBackgroundDrawable(nameOfBitmapDrawable);

So all you will have to do is save that image (the one in your post) as a drawable (transparent PNG perhaps) and then convert that Drawable into a Bitmap. From there, you just have to follow the steps I outlined above. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I do upscale an image it gets pixelated which does look awful.

Comment: This might or might not work: create a high resolution, large-sized version of the box and then rescale it to something smaller/to fit your needs using the method I suggested in the answer. This approach helped me prevent pixelation, however, in my case I had to scale a large scaled Photo to a small thumbnail. Let me know if this approach works.

Comment: Well that's really not the way I want to do this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:shape="rectangle"
             >
  <gradient android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:centerColor="#00ccff" 
            android:startColor="#000000"
           /> 
  <corners android:radius="5dp" /> 
  </shape>
Try this
```

Comment: That is a totally different looking shape.